# I can`t reorder apps in Djnago-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can`t admin apps reorder my apps.
In django admin home I have the message "Site administration
You don’t have permission to view or edit anything."

```
DEFAULT_APPS = (
    'admin_reorder',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder',    
]

ADMIN_REORDER = (
    "apps.accounts", "apps.questions", "apps.exams", "apps.settings"
)
```

Comment: Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and the layout of the app folders in your project.

Comment: The user used to log in into the admin, is a superuser ? Here  django-modeladmin-reorder documentation:  https://pypi.org/project/django-modeladmin-reorder/

Answer (score 0):

Re-ordering your apps in django admin is as below: 
**First, you need to define the order you want you apps, in your settings.py file**

```
#settings.py
from collections import OrderedDict

APP_ORDER = OrderedDict([
  ("products", ["Categories", "Products"]),
  ("orders", ["ClientOrders", "Supplies"]),
  ("administration", ["Clients", "Companies"]),
])
```

**Second, you need to write a template tag to enforce the ordering** 
create a folder in any of your app, called **templatetags**; in this folder you can call the file 'sort_app.py' or whatever name you like. I am creating mine in one of my apps called 'administration'. The content of this file is:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()


def pop_and_get_app(apps, key, app_label):
    for index, app in enumerate(apps):
        if app[key] == app_label:
            obj = apps.pop(index)
            return obj
    return None


@register.filter
def sort_apps(apps):
    new_apps = []
    order = settings.APP_ORDER
    for app_label in order.keys():
        obj = pop_and_get_app(apps, "app_label", app_label)
        new_apps.append(obj) if obj else None
    apps = new_apps + apps
    for app in apps:
        models = app.get("models")
        app_label = app.get("app_label")
        new_models = []
        order_models = settings.APP_ORDER.get(app_label, [])
        for model in order_models:
            obj = pop_and_get_app(models, "object_name", model)
            new_models.append(obj) if obj else None
        models = new_models + models
        app["models"] = models
    return apps
```

create another file, in the same folder called **base.py**, with content as;

```
from inspect import getfullargspec

from django.template.library import InclusionNode, parse_bits


class InclusionAdminNode(InclusionNode):
    """
    Template tag that allows its template to be overridden per model, per app,
    or globally.
    """

    def __init__(self, parser, token, func, template_name, takes_context=True):
        self.template_name = template_name
        params, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonly, kwonly_defaults, _ = getfullargspec(func)
        bits = token.split_contents()
        args, kwargs = parse_bits(
            parser, bits[1:], params, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonly,
            kwonly_defaults, takes_context, bits[0],
        )
        super().__init__(func, takes_context, args, kwargs, filename=None)

    def render(self, context):
        opts = context['opts']
        app_label = opts.app_label.lower()
        object_name = opts.object_name.lower()
        # Load template for this render call. (Setting self.filename isn't
        # thread-safe.)
        context.render_context[self] = context.template.engine.select_template([
            'admin/%s/%s/%s' % (app_label, object_name, self.template_name),
            'admin/%s/%s' % (app_label, self.template_name),
            'admin/%s' % self.template_name,
        ])
        return super().render(context)
```

**Lastly, you need to register the template tag, in your settings.py file, in the "TEMPLATES" section**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
          ...
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'admin_tags':  'administration.templatetags.sort_apps',
            }
        },
    },
]
```